# Prove the equality of derivative maps for the following function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f : \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ be a function. Let $L_a : \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ and let $L_b : \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ be linear transformations. Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $a$ with derivative $L_a$, and $f$ is differentiable at a with derivative $L_b$. Then $L_a = L_b$.

I'm trying to prove it by contradiction, I assume that $L_a \ne L_b$. But I  have problems with the definition of differentiability, I can't get to the contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $L_a \neq L_b$, then $L_a(u) \neq L_b(u)$ for some $u \neq 0$. Further, if

$$f(a+h) = f(a) + L_a(h) + R_a(h)$$

and

$$f(a+h) = f(a) + L_b(h) + R_b(h)$$
for any $h \in \Bbb{R}^n$, can both  $\lim_{|h|\rightarrow 0} \frac{|R_a(h)|}{|h|}$ and $\lim_{|h|\rightarrow 0} \frac{|R_b(h)|}{|h|}$  tends to $0$?

One more hint: Consider scalar multiples of $u$.